# How to download git files in virtual machine from local machine and make them updateable

Tags: git, github, vagrant, virtualbox, ubuntu-16.04

I'm using vagrant for development and in vagrant I installed ubuntu/xenial64 (Ubuntu 16.04 TLS) for odoo development.

In this virtual machine with ubuntu, if i want to download a github repository into a folder inside the system itself, I will do like this:

```
root@ubuntu:~# mkdir /opt/odoo 'create directory
root@ubuntu:~# sudo git clone https://www.github.com/odoo/odoo --depth 1 --branch 10.0 --single-branch /opt/odoo 'download git online
```

The above works perfectly.

What if I want to download a local git file from my Windows Machine (the host):

```
C:/GitHub/odoo
```

into my ubuntu (Virtual Machine) folder at:

```
/opt/odoo
```

I know that I can copy pasting the local git files from Windows into ubuntu VM (it is possible) but in this case I need to make the git files in ubuntu VM update-able so that if I give a command in ubuntu VM like this:

```
sudo git fetch upstream 10.0
sudo git pull upstream 10.0
```

The above command will fetch and pull the git files from Windows into my ubuntu VM where the origin path is

```
C:/GitHub/odoo
```

Is this possible?

I was thinking about making a shared directory in ubuntu that can communicate with the host machine where ubuntu can read the file at C:/Github/odoo but I'm not sure how to achieve this in ubuntu minimal setup or is this the only approach?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Local git repos are not intended to be copied. Just push any changes and then download them on the other OS.

Comment: One reason why is, because I need to work offline and I want to be able to edit my codes using an IDE directly in WIndows Machine (example using Intellij IDEA) and my git files are stored in an offline disk. I thought it is possible with vagrant because long time ago when I use vagrant for  laravel development the VM can actually read the development files directly from Windows and this changes also can be read by Virtual Machine. But for this purpose I'm confused because it's related to git.

Comment: That is not how git was intended to be used. The method I suggested is the proper method.

Comment: I notice some of my comments were deleted here with no reason maybe it sounds like I was trying to argue. I understand this is an old question, Last time I did not have time to explain why I need this. Git can work offline You can have a desktop computer to host offline git repo and use your laptop to make commit, pull, push from the desktop git repo. So, that is another way to use git. By the way, my question has been answered by @Frederic Henri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was thinking about making a shared directory in ubuntu that can communicate with the host machine where ubuntu can read the file at C:/Github/odoo but I'm not sure how to achieve this in ubuntu minimal setup or is this the only approach?

You're right, just use a shared folder between your host machine (windows) and the VM so any changes on one will be reflected in the other, you will be able to pull/push from windows or the VM.

Just add the following in your vagrant file

```
config.vm.synced_folder "C:/GitHub/odoo", "/opt/odoo", owner: "root", group: "root"
```